# Breakdown data in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I elegantly turn the below into JSON so that each element in "data" (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5) are separate and easily traversed without using str_replace or preg_replace?

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":{
      "1":"this is an element",
      "2":"this is an element",
      "3":"this is an element",
      "4":"this is an element",
      "5":"this is an element",
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "separate and easily traversed"? Is it not already JSON?

Comment: Already looks like JSON and it seems you already have five separate entries in `data`.

Comment: Simply `json_decode` it, what does str_replace have to do anything with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean you already have a JSON string, use `json_decode()`, and supply the second argument as `true` to get an associative array of the decoded JSON.

```
$str = '{"status":"success","data":{"1":"this is an element","2":"this is an element","3":"this is an element","4":"this is an element","5":"this is an element"}}'
$json = json_decode($str, true);
```

The variable `$json` will be an associative array.